# C Dynamic char array

Tags: c

Expanding array dynamicly after user enter string in function `dynamic_array` My Problem seems to be when i try to use the extended array agian in main after i `dynamic_array` returns true.

After function call i try to print `input` with `printf("main string: %s\n", input)` the program will crash. It seems like the `*input` in `main` never gets extended.

```
int dynamic_array(char *input, int *string_current_len){
  int string_len = 0;
  char temp_c;

  input = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));

  if(input == NULL) {
    printf("Could not allocate memory!");
    exit(1);
  }  

  printf("File to search in: ");

  while((temp_c = getchar()) != '\n') {
    realloc(input, (sizeof(char)));
    input[string_len++] = temp_c;
  }

  input[string_len] = '\0';

  printf("\nYou entered the string: %s\n", input);
  printf("length of string is %d.\n", string_len);


  *string_current_len = string_len;
  return 1;
}


int main(void) {
  int string_len = 0;
  char *input;

  printf("enter #q as filename or word to quit.\n");
      if(!dynamic_array(input, &string_len)){
       return 0;
      }

   printf("main string: %s\n", input);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation of every function you are using, e.g. [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html), [printf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html), ...

Comment: Yeah i read about that it can be expensive, i want to understand it completely before taking actaully resource use into count.

Comment: First try to write a *correct* program. Later consider optimizing it.

Comment: If i could write a correct program i would´t be asking, would i?

Comment: I mean that you should not care about `malloc` being expansive. But you should think hard about the size requested to `malloc` and you should usually initialize or clear the freshly allocated memory zone just after the `malloc`. Don't forget that `malloc` can fail, so test that case too.

Comment: the function dynamic_array() exits with a 1 when there is an error, which would be the same exit if only one char read from the input. Note: the function main() is expecting a 0 return when an error occurs in dynamic_array().  the result is when there is an error in dynamic_array() main() goes ahead and trys to print input.  But input could be pointing anywhere.

Comment: the function getchar() could return EOF, but that is not being checked.  The function realloc() can fail, so that needs to be checked.

Comment: this line: printf("Could not allocate memory!"); should be perror("Could not allocate memory!"); so the reason for the error is also printed and the output is on stderr rather than stdout

Answer (score 6):

This:

```
realloc(input, (sizeof(char)));
```

is wrong. The `realloc()` function doesn't modify the given pointer (it can't!), it *returns* the new pointer. It can also fail, and return `NULL`.

Also, the second argument doesn't make any sense at all, it should be the new desired *total size* of the previously allocated buffer, but you're always passing (a very obscure) 1. It's not "grow this by this amount", it's the rather more low-level "attempt to grow this to this new size, and return the new location of the grown buffer".

Please read [the documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc) very carefully.

Comment: So realloc will return with a new pointer of input with the number of string_len +1 of type char?

Comment: @Nicco Please read the documentation. It will return with a newly allocated buffer of the requested length, which begins with the data that was in the original buffer, or `NULL` on failure. It's also possible that it returns the same pointer value, if it managed to grow the allocation in place.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!dynamic_array(input, &string_len)){
return 0;
}
```

"input" variable is used without initialization.

realloc(input, (sizeof(char)));

Above "realloc" is returning bad pointer. It may be totally bogus, or it may have been allocated from another heap. The pointer MUST come from the 'local' heap.

Comment: True. And the value is not used in the function at all. But that should be rather a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
realloc(input, (sizeof(char)));
```

You are reallocating with same size (i.e 1 byte). It shoud be:

```
while((temp_c = getchar()) != '\n') {
    realloc(input, (string_len + 1) * (sizeof(char)));
    input[string_len++] = temp_c;
```

Comment: if this suggestion is used, then the line: input[string_len] = '\0'; will fail because it will be writing past the end of the allocated buffer.

Comment: Yes i agree. The fix would be to add `realloc(input, (string_len + 1) * (sizeof(char)));` before `input[string_len] = '\0';` line.

Answer (score 0):

C has a [call-by-value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value) semantics. So any changes to formal `input` inside `dynamic_array` is *not* propagated to the caller (e.g. your `main`).

Your `main` does not initialize `input`. If you compiled with all warnings and debug info (as you should), e.g. with `gcc -Wall -g`, you'll get a warning about that.

<sup>I actually recommend to initialize *every* local variable. This makes the debugging easier (since runs are more reproductible). Useless initializations will be removed by the optimizer.</sup>

You could initialize `input` inside your `main` with

```
  char* input = NULL;
```

and you should redesign your program, perhaps by having a `grow_array` function (instead of your `dynamic_array`) which you would call in your `main` like

```
 grow_array (&input, &string_len);
```

I leave up to you to declare and implement `grow_array` correctly. I'm too lame to do your homework.

Inside your `grow_array` you want to call `malloc` and test it:

```
*pptr = malloc(newsize);
if (!*pptr) { perror ("malloc"); exit (EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

Don't forget to use the debugger (`gdb`) to run your program *step by step*.

<sup>I don't recommend using `realloc` because error handling could be tricky. I would suggest using `malloc` and `free` and *cleverly* copying the data using [mempcy](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_memcpy.htm).</sup>

Read the documentation of every function that you are using, e.g. [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html), [printf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html)

Answer (score 0):

couple of things that I noticed.

```
int dynamic_array(char *input, int *string_current_len) should change to 
int dynamic_array(char **input, int *string_current_len)
```

since this function is trying to modify a pointer.
 also the call to the function here

```
 if(!dynamic_array(input, &string_len)){
       return 0;
      }
```

needs to be:

```
if(!dynamic_array(&input, &string_len)){
       return 0;
      }
```